# Does my Postgres instance support IEEE 754 double precision floats?

Tags: postgresql, double, ieee-754

[According to the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) Postgres `double precision` type implements IEEE 754 : “The data types real and double precision are inexact, variable-precision numeric types. On all currently supported platforms, these types are implementations of IEEE Standard 754 for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (single and double precision, respectively), to the extent that the underlying processor, operating system, and compiler support it.”

My question is then how do I check that "the underlying processor, operating system, and compiler support it"? Is it somewhat common that this is not the case?

**Clarification**

I want to check if my specific Postgres instance is compliant. Is there some kind of test(s) that I can do running SQL queries in order to verify or disprove that?

Comment: I feel like https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/sql/float8.sql;h=03c134b07854b0968253fa58ebb96604149f7c51;hb=f4fb45d15c59d7add2e1b81a9d477d0119a9691a#l306 answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common for today's computers to use IEEE 754 floating point numbers. So much so that even in the wide range of platforms supported by PostgreSQL, all do. The only way to check is to look at the specification and documentation of the hardware or software in question.

PostgreSQL uses whatever the compiler and machine provide for the C data type `double`. It does not implement floating point arithmetic itself.

Comment: Using IEEE-754 floating-point numbers does not mean using IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic. C implementations may use the IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) format for `double` but flush subnormals to zero or contract expressions in ways that do not conform to the IEEE-754 rules (such as used a fused multiply-add where the source code has a separate multiply and add). So, if PostgreSQL is using whatever the compiler and machine provide for the C data type `double`, it is doubtful that all in the range of supported platforms actually provide arithmetic that conforms to IEEE-754.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is a very helpful comment. That's probably what people had in mind when they wrote the weasel words "to the extent that the underlying processor, operating system, and compiler support it.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you aware of specific examples where this is not the case?

Comment: @NicolaAmbrosetti: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/cxs8h8eqY) is an example where Godbolt appears to flush a subnormal result to zero, when `-ffast-math` is used. Removing `-ffast-math` changes the result fro “0xp+0” to “0x1p-140”. Whether a C implementation, including the operating system and the default modes set for programs, will flush subnormals may depend on switches used, whether SIMD features are used, the operating system version, and so on, and I do not have up-to-date information on those details.